# Executing tracerouter with ipv6 but return the destination different to given address

Tags: networking, ipv6

As the question, I executed this

```
traceroute -6 -q 1 -n 2a02:26f0:7000:19a::2eb8 > V6.txt 2>&1
```

And returns the result as:

```
traceroute to 2a02:26f0:7000:19a::2eb8 (2a02:26f0:7000:19a::2eb8), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
 1  2001:630:40:f00:e22f:6dff:fe2c:ed80  0.301 ms
 2  2001:630:40:20::11  0.346 ms
 3  *
 4  2001:630:0:900c::1  0.702 ms
 5  2001:630:0:10::185  1.082 ms
 6  2001:630:0:10::1fd  5.881 ms
 7  2001:630:0:10::8e  5.496 ms
 8  2001:630:0:8088::6  5.719 ms
 9  2a02:26f0:7000::48f7:b0c6  5.639 ms
```

Why the packet go to 2a02:26f0:7000::48f7:b0c6 instead of 2a02:26f0:7000:19a::2eb8?